# How do I open a file using a variable/string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm just a beginner. I'm using ASP.NET / VB and I want to store some image filenames as strings. How do I open an image file when I have the path saved in the variable 'avatar'? For example: if I do...

```
Dim avatar As String = "~/files/images/avatars/L01 copy.gif"
```

How do I open the image? Here's the line I have at the moment...

```
<asp:Image ID="Imageavatar" width="80px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/avatars/L01 copy.gif" />
```

I want to replace the last part to be something like `ImageUrl=avatar`

Comment: Is this Image just on your page, or is it within a GridView, Repeater, or other templated control?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, getting a titch confused now even though I know this is probably really easy, I've tried the following which didn't work..

VB..
Dim avatar As String = "~/files/images/avatars/L01 copy.gif"
Imageavatar.ImageUrl = avatar

Front End..
<asp:Image ID="Imageavatar" width="80px" runat="server" ImageUrl=avatar />

Comment: It's just on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind file (the .aspx.vb file), put this piece of code to assign the value of `avatar` to the `ImageUrl` property of the `asp:Image`:

```
Imageavatar.ImageUrl = avatar
```